# How to put polynomials in sine function? (re)

Tags: c

Hi i'm making some program to find the solution of different sine functions.
I wanted to sin(2x), sin(4x), sin(6x), .... sin(12x) and store them to array, so that i can test each function's solution on given interval.

Here' s the code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

int bisect(double *x, double x0, double xf, double tolerance, double (*func)(double));


int main()
{
    double x, x0 = 2.0, xf = 4.0, tolerance = FLT_EPSILON;
    int status, i, j;
    double (*pf[6])(double);

    for (i = 1; i < 7; i++)
    {   
        pf[i] = sin(2 * i * x);
        // error : cannot assign double value to double(*) (double) entity 
        // How to make functions like sin(2x), sin(4x), .. etc??
        status = bisect(&x, x0, xf, tolerance, pf[i]);
```

And i created bisect() function to find at what point given function returns 0.

bisection function is below the main function. x0 is start point, xf is end point, i set tolerance for checking error. bisect function uses intermediate value theorem in for loop.

I want to find solution by calling bisect function in for loop, and delivering sine functions using *pf[i].

```
        if (status == -1)
            printf("Error : bisect() failed, invalid tolerance\n");
        else if(status == -2)
            printf("Error : bisect() failed, invalid end points\n");
        else
            printf("x = %f, sin(x) = %g\n", x, pf[i](x));


    }
    return 0;
}

int bisect(double *x, double x0, double xf, double tolerance, double (*func)(double))
{
    double xleft = x0, fleft;
    double xright = xf;
    double xmid, fmid;

    if (tolerance <= 0.0)
        return -1;

    fleft = func(x0);

    if (fleft * func(xf) > 0.0)
        return -2;

    xmid = (xleft+xright) /2.0;
    fmid = func(xmid);

    while (fabs(fmid) > tolerance)
    {
        if (fleft * fmid <= 0)
        {
            xright = xmid;
        }

        else
        {
            xleft = xmid;
            fleft = fmid;
        }
        xmid = (xleft + xright) / 2.0;
        fmid = func(xmid);

    }
    *x = xmid;
    return 0;
}
```

it's easy to find solution for sin, cos, etc. but what about sin(2x), sin(4x), etc?? how can i store those functions in *pf[]?? (array of function pointers)

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: You already posted this question some hours ago. Re-posts are not well received here. You should have edited the original and ask for re-open (in case it was closed). Note that this one is not really better. You got information in the comments, you seem not to have thought about. Read [ask]. We are not a tutoring/coding site.

Comment: @Olaf my apologies. I will do better next time. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C it's not possible to do what you want, not without creating multiple functions wrapping the original `sin` function.

Perhaps something like

```
double sin2(double value)
{
    return sin(2 * value);
}

double sin4(double value)
{
    return sin(4 * value);
}

// Etc...

int main(void)
{
    double (*pf[6])(double) = {
        sin2, sin4, ...
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        printf("%f\n", pf[i](0.5));
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help! How did you do that so easy? :)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, C does not support full-fledged closures, which is what you seem to want.

However, you should be able to define any custom function in your program to take a `double` and return `double`, and pass that to your bisect function.

For instance:

```
double some_function(double x) {
     // You can do anything you like, as long as you return a double.
     return sin(2 * x);
}
```

In your case, it may be a little tedious to have to separately specify a custom function for every value of `i`, but you could possibly get rid of some repetition by using a macro, such as:

```
#define DEFINE_SIN_POLY(i) double sin_poly_##i##(double x) { \
   return sin(2 * i * x); \
}

DEFINE_SIN_POLY(2);
DEFINE_SIN_POLY(3); // etc.

// then, you can simply access these functions as
sin_poly_2, sin_poly_3, etc.
```

This, however, is a little ugly. If you were to use C++, you could take advantage of more advanced features, such as function types, lambdas, etc., to make your code more concise, with almost no loss in terms of performance.

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks for keeping my code from long winded.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help, even if by a little bit. Again, as stated before, if all you care about is quickly prototyping algorithms and playing around, something like C++, or even Python, may make you much more productive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create functions on the fly, that have some sort of memory of what the parameters are. You clould either make these parameters global, or create what is called a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

Even though C itself has no support for such a thing, you could emulate it, by creating a new function on the heap that has the desired behavior. There are libraries that help you do this.

libffi is such a library that allows you to create a closure in C, though it is quite an advanced technique.

The documentation provides some examples: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/libffi-dev/html/Closure-Example.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that

```
pf[i] = sin(2 * i * x);
```

calls the `sin()` function with argument equal to the current value of `2*i*x`.  The result is the sine of that particular value, not a function.

Essentially, Standard C does not support closures.

The easiest way to get the required effects, rather than trying to directly or indirectly create a set of functions within the loop, would be to change the specification of `bisect()` from

```
int bisect(double *x, double x0, double xf, double tolerance, double (*func)(double))
```

to add an extra argument

```
int bisect(double *x, double x0, double xf, double tolerance, double (*func)(double), double factor)
```

and, in every place where `func(something)` is called, change to `func(something*factor)`.   For example, change `fmid = func(xmid)` to `fmid = func(xmid * factor)`.

Then in the caller (`main()`) change the loop from

```
for (i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{   
    pf[i] = sin(2 * i * x);
    // error : cannot assign double value to double(*) (double) entity 
    // How to make functions like sin(2x), sin(4x), .. etc??
    status = bisect(&x, x0, xf, tolerance, pf[i]);
```

to

```
for (i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{   
    // How to make functions like sin(2x), sin(4x), .. etc
    status = bisect(&x, x0, xf, tolerance, sin, 2*i);
```

Note that this eliminates the need for the array `pf` entirely.   It works by passing the value of `2*i` to the function, as `factor`, which can then be used.

More generally, however, you need to take the time to read a C textbook.   Trying to learn C by analogy with Python will cause you all sorts of problems, since Python supports quite a few features (like closures in this case) that C does not, and that cannot easily be mimicked in C.   They are very different languages and often require VERY different ways of structuring a program.

Comment: It's really neat way of doing things. Thanks for your help. And i will keep on reading C books, instead of youtube.